# Does anyone have a list of areas with cooking stations?

Tags: kingdom-come-deliverance

I have been taking them for granted and am in Uzhitz with the need to cook some appropriated game meat. But I'm noticing I am possibly blind as a bat, but I sort of assumed all pub/inns had one. And now that I'm posting this, I'm remembering some inns did not have my free pot of food waiting for me on my return.

So, does anyone have a list? Otherwise, I'll start writing them down and post here eventually.

Comment: I noticed inside the inn there is one. I typically look for the kettle over a fire, so I'll be keeping my eyes out for a list if no one else wants to put one up.

Comment: The game seems to make a difference between the types of food you can cook : vegetables and the likes can be cooked at (most) cooking pots, while meats can/must be cooked on embers or grills (which are usally nearby).